# I'm trying to increment a pointer through an array of structs - my solution works but does so in a non-intuitive way

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So, I've put all my "printf debugging" in the code to display what effect I'm talking about. I enclosed them in multi-line comments /* with star banners to easily identify them if you want to run the program and just nix/delete the code blocks as they don't serve any other purpose than explaining what I'm trying to say.

Backstory: I was attempting to create a tic-tac-toe game and I'm almost done, but I can't seem to understand why incrementing a pointer across an array of structs by the size of that struct doesn't move by one index after each increment and instead moves by 3. Below is the code so far.

Essentially, the address is staying the same, the pointer is pointing at the correct places, everything is working but I don't understand the logic at line 186, near the very end of the program within the locationfinder function's scope. I don't understand why incrementing the pointer by a size of a struct (which is what one index in an array contains) doesn't work and I have to resort to incrementing by ^ that *divided* by 3...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define height 3
#define width 3

//STRUCT DEFINITIONS--
struct square //the size of a struct of type square is 8 bytes (this is important info for the issue)
{
    char input;
    int location;
};

struct playermoves //unnecessary struct but ignore
{
    struct square array[height][width];

}table;

//PROTOTYPES--
void displaytable(void); //displays the table
void script1(void); //prints the instruction script
void game(int count); //runs the game operations
char * locationfinder(int * locationpointer, int reference); //cross-checks the chosen tic-tac-toe table location a player
                                                            //inputs by storing as "int reference"
//winchecker(int loc); - function not yet written



int main(void)
{
    //below is a loop filling table with 'c' for 'clear' and adding locations as integers assigned to each cell
    int locations = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            table.array[i][j].input = 'c';
            table.array[i][j].location = locations;
            locations++;
        }
    }
    printf("TIC TAC TOE\n");
    //sleep(2);
    printf("\n\n\n Players, this is your table. It is set to clear right now, using the character 'c'\n");
    displaytable();
    //sleep(7);
    printf("\n\n");

    int turn = 1;

    script1();
    //below runs through the maximum moves (9) that could be made in a game with a 9 squared table
    //and decides who's turn it is on each iteration
    int allsquares = height*width;
    for(int i = 1; i < (allsquares+1); i++) //setting i to 1, instead of zero, for the modulus "turn" decider to work
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            turn = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            turn = 1;
        }
        game(turn);
    }

}

void script1(void)
{
    printf("Player 1, your character is alphabetical 'X'\n");
    //sleep(3);
    printf("Player 2, your character is alphabetical 'O'\n");
    printf("_\n_\n");
    //sleep(5);
    printf("You can see the table at any time by typing 'd' on your turn, in lower case\n");
    printf("_\n_\n");
    //sleep(3);
    printf("Are you both ready? Game start!\n");
    //sleep(3);
}

void game(int turn)
{
    int move;
    if(turn == 1) //player one's round
    {
        do
        {
            char play = '\0';
            move = 0;
            printf("====================================================================================================\n");
            printf("Player 1, what is your move?\nInput the location of the square you want to put your counter X into.\n");

            scanf("%i", &move); //scanning for a location (integer) input
            scanf("%c", &play); //scanning for a character shortcut, 'd', which displays the table
            if(play == 'd')
            {
                displaytable();
                sleep(2);
            }
        }while(move == '\0' || move < 1 || move > 9); //if move is empty, or out of bounds of locations available on table, repeat prompt

        /**********************************************************************************************************************
        printf("\n\nPRINTF DEBUGGING: \n(these addresses should correspond with those referenced below in the locationfinder scope):\n");
        printf("SCOPE: main\n"); 
        for(int a = 0, counter = 1; a < height; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b < width; b++)
            {
                    printf("Location %i of cell %i: is %p\n", counter, counter, &table.array[a][b].location);
                    counter++;
            }
        }
        ***************************************************************************************************************/

        //address returned in the form of 'char * locationfinder' to char input field of array location that user inputted
        char * editor = locationfinder(&table.array[0][0].location, move);
        *editor = 'X'; //value modified by editor pointer to reflect player's move

    }
    else if(turn == 2)
    {
        do
        {
            char play = '\0';
            move = 0;
            printf("====================================================================================================\n");
            printf("Player 2, what is your move?\nInput the location of the square you want to put your counter O into.\n");

            scanf("%d", &move); //scanning for a location (integer) input
            scanf("%c", &play); //scanning for a character shortcut, 'd', which displays the table
            if(play == 'd')
            {
                displaytable();
                sleep(2);
            }
        }while(move == '\0' || move < 1 || move > 9); //if move is empty, or out of bounds of locations available on table, repeat prompt

        //address returned in the form of 'char * locationfinder' to char input field of array location that user inputted
        char * editor = locationfinder(&table.array[0][0].location, move);
        *editor = 'O'; //value modified by editor pointer to reflect player's move
    }
    //winchecker function to go here
}

void displaytable(void)
{
    printf("+=========+=========+=========+\n");
    printf("|1.  %c    |4.   %c    |7.  %c   |\n", table.array[0][0].input, table.array[1][0].input, table.array[2][0].input);
    printf("+---------+---------+---------+\n");
    printf("|2.  %c    |5.   %c    |8.  %c   |\n", table.array[0][1].input, table.array[1][1].input, table.array[2][1].input);
    printf("+---------+---------+---------+\n");
    printf("|3.  %c    |6.   %c    |9.  %c   |\n", table.array[0][2].input, table.array[1][2].input, table.array[2][2].input);
    printf("+=========+=========+=========+\n");
}

//locationfinder below contains loop which cross-checks the user inputted location (integer)
//with the value at the .location member field of each 'square' array

char * locationfinder(int * locationpointer, int reference)
{
    /****************************************************************************************************************************
    printf("\n\nThe location pointer  in the locationfinder scope should display the same addresses as those in the loop in Main.\n");
    printf("As you can see above, these addresses (of the location member fields in the array) increment in hexadecimal by 8 bytes\n");
    printf("As you will see below, the incrementation of the pointer in locationfinder scope does so too**\n");
    printf("This is because sizeof(struct square) also returns 8 bytes: %lu\n", sizeof(struct square));
    printf("**^So why must the incrementation for this pointer in the loop below be set to sizeof(struct square)/3 to work?\n");
    
    printf("\nSCOPE: locationfinder.\n");
    ************************************************************************************************************************/
    int runtime = height*width;
    for(int i = 0; i < runtime; i++)
    {
        /**************************************************************************************************
        printf("Location %i at cell %i: is %p\n", i+1, i+1, locationpointer);
        **************************************************************************************************/

        if(*locationpointer == reference)
        {
            char * play = (char*)locationpointer-sizeof(int); //moving the pointer to the char input field
            return play; //returning this pointer
        }
        locationpointer += sizeof(struct square)/3; //not locationpointer+= sizeof(struct square) ???
        // it should increment with sizeof(struct square) properly, but it doesn't
    }
    //disregard below
    char m = 'm';
    char * zero = &m;
    return zero;
}
```

Comment: Increment a pointer by `1` to move to the next element. Just like with array indexing. You do not need to "increment a pointer by the size of the struct" if the pointer is the correct type.

Comment: Aside: in `scanf("%c", &play);` you'll proably need a space like this: `scanf(" %c", &play);`

Comment: Also `return zero` leads to undefined behaviour: returning address of local variable.

Comment: @Weather Vane thank you for the corrections :) I'm a little confused though. I tried to run the location finder function without anything returned, other than the return statement in the 'i' loop's if-branch and it gave me grief so I just tacked something on at the end to stop the error messages (bad, I know). What would I do instead in such a case? Also why the space in scanf?

Comment: The `scanf` conversion stops at the first character it cannot convert, which is typically (but not necessarily) a space or a newline, and that character remains in the input buffer. It will be read by the *next* `scanf()`. Format specifiers `%d` and `%s` and `%f` automatically filter such leading whitespace characters, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. You can instruct `scanf` to do so by adding a space just before the `%`.

Comment: @WeatherVane ohhhh wow I never knew that!! I thought every format specifier automatically filtered that. Thank you so much for that info!!

Answer (score 0):

If `p` is a pointer to some type *T* and `n` is an integer, `p + n` points to the `n`th element of the array of objects of type *T* starting at `p`. In particular, `p + 1` is the next element of the array. [Pointer arithmetic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Pointer_arithmetic) operates on *pointers*, not addresses.

`p + n` points to `p[n]`. In fact, that's how `p[n]` is defined: it's a nicer way of writing `*(p + n)`.

So `locationpointer += sizeof(struct square)/3` works because on your system, `sizeof(struct square)` happens to be 3. The correct way of writing this is

```
locationpointer += 1;
```

or

```
locationpointer++;
```

or

```
++locationpointer;
```

---

The line above `char * play = (char*)locationpointer-sizeof(int);` is also wrong but happens to work on your platform. `(char*)locationpointer-sizeof(int)` points `sizeof(int)` elements before `(char*)locationpointer`. Since `(char*)locationpointer` is a pointer to `char` and `sizeof(char)` is required to be 1, this does point to the address that is `sizeof(int)` bytes before `locationpointer`. So far so good.

The problem is that on some platforms, this is not the address of the `location` field of the previous `struct square`! Most platforms require an `int` to be stored in memory at an address that's a multiple of `sizeof(int)`, or at least there's a performance penalty if this is not the case. This requirement is called [alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). Due to alignment requirements, compilers can and often do put *padding* in structures. Padding can appear both between fields and at the end of a structure.

On many platforms, `int` must be at an even address, which requires padding before the `location` field. On a few platforms, `int` can be unaligned but some other types (pointers, floats) have an alignment requirement (typically 4 or 8), and as a consequence all structures have a size that's a multiple of 4 or 8, which requires padding at the end of the structure. With padding at the end, `(char*)locationpointer-sizeof(int)` does not point to the `location` field, but a little further in memory.

The correct way to write this line is to take the address of the structure element.

```
#include <stddef.h>
…
int* play = &(locationpointer-1)->location;
```

You should also change `locationfinder` to return `int*`. It doesn't make sense to cast the value to a `char*`.

Comment: `sizeof(struct square)/3` would be `2` on any reasonable modern desktop compiler. ...which is what by pure (bad?) luck  happens to give next square when adding to an `int *`.  Be aware that most pointer arithmetic done by OP is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pointer to a struct member, you can find the pointer to owning `struct` like this:

```
 struct square * get_square(int *locationptr)
 {
    return (struct square *) ((char *)locationptr - offsetof(struct square, location));
 }
```

But if you want to lookup a struct in an array, based on member value, it is better to pass pointer to first element of array, and lookup member from that, rather than other way around, passing pointer to member of first element and trying to calculating pointer to struct.

```
struct square *locationfinder(struct square squares[height][width], int reference)
{
   for (int l = 0; l < height; l++)
     for (int c = 0; c < width; c++)
        if (squares[l][c].location == reference)
           return &(squares[l][c]);
   return NULL;
}
```

But since the value of `location` can be calculated based on the position in array, we really don't need to access its member to do a lookup.

```
 /*
    `label` is a number 1..9 referencing a square on the board.
    we call it label rather than index, because indexes are *always*
    zero based in C
 */
 struct square *label2square(struct square squares[height][width], int label)
 {
     /* We need something zero-based for calculation */
     int index = label - 1;
     if ((index < 0) || (index >= width*height))
        return NULL;

     int line = index/width;
     int column = index%width;
     return &(squares[line][column]);
 }
```

Doing this, I also don't see any need for the `location` member in `struct square`.

Just an added comment, your display function has a bug, it uses `array[column][line]` rather than `array[line][column]`

Comment: THANK YOU!!! your answer is really common-sense and beautiful to look at. I can only hope my solutions become as efficient as yours over time. Reading this is like someone opening your eyes after you've had tunnel vision, lol, because you're right, I don't actually need the location field and it's shocking me. Also, I never would've thought of line & column being calculated that way! Again, thank you for explaining what I was doing wrong so far here and in your replies and providing another perspective. I think I need to read up on pointer arithmetic and the proper way to do it.